# Как реализовать LocalStorage?

Tags: jquery, localstorage

Как в нижеуказанном коде реализовать LocalStorage? Чтобы значения не обнулялись при обновлении страницы.
[Код - jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k7aw2Lzr/9/)

```js
$("#delivery-now").on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$('#delivery-now').hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).toggleClass('active', true);
    $("#delivery-time").removeClass('active');
  }
});
$("#delivery-time").on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$('#delivery-time').hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).toggleClass('active', true);
    $("#delivery-now").removeClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  border: 3px red solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>Когда доставить</label>
  <div>
    <input id="delivery-now" class="active" type="button" value="Доставить сейчас">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="delivery-time" type="button" value="Доставить ко времени">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В конце обоих обработчиков:

```
localStorage.setItem("activeButton", $(".active").attr("id"));
```

На загрузке страницы:

```
var activeId = localStorage.getItem("activeButton");
if (activeId) {
  //$(".active").removeClass("active");
  //$("#" + activeId).addClass("active"); 
  // чтобы выполнялись действия по нажатию:
  $("#" + activeId).click();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Это работает.
Не могу понять как заставить другие блоки работать с localstorage. Можете помочь? https://jsfiddle.net/k7aw2Lzr/27/

Comment: @ОлегНечаев Изменил. Если я Вас правильно понял.

Comment: Спасибо! Сделал аналогичное для других обработчиков. А можно этот код сократить? https://pastebin.com/1kdRt9s7